# What is the Hasidic view of humility?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, humble

I remember reading something to the effect that Hasidic thinking is that humility is not thinking *little* of yourself, it is not thinking of yourself *at all*.  Is this accurate and what is the source?

Comment: You might be thinking of [this concept](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/ביטול)

Comment: Nobody says that humility is thinking little of yourself. Humility is recognizing that your talents are meant to be used in the service of Hashem and were given to you by Him.

Comment: I would be surprised that your assumption is true. That completely contradicts the "fundamental" law of the Torah, "Love your neighbor as you would yourself." How would one be able to make a proper application of this mitzvah if he didn't love himself at all? To me, that doesn't sound like humility at all; it sounds like foolishness.

Comment: @DanF I think that's the difference between thinking about one's worth and just making choices that are to one's benefit.